# Dealing with mp4 files in memory with ffprobe

Tags: .net-core, ffmpeg

In the uploading file process, I want to manipulate the content in the memory without saving the file to the disk. For that purpose, I'm using `FFmpeg` with converting `IFormFile` into `MemoryStream` and further on I'm using FFmpeg to change the content and output the result into pipe again for further processing. This whole works fine with the exception that some files cannot be processed.

*Again, I'm not dealing with direct files during the process but their memory stream representation.*

When I examine 1st file details using ffprobe I'm getting

```
format": {
        "filename": "file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "30.526667",
        "size": "1570024",
        "bit_rate": "411449",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "mp42",
            "minor_version": "0",
            "compatible_brands": "mp42mp41isomavc1",
            "creation_time": "2015-08-07T09:13:02.000000Z"
        }
    }
```

Memory stream representation of this file as input pipe in the command can be processed and output as expected.

```
ffmpeg -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -s 800x600 -f mpeg pipe:1
```

Error:  update with full error message

> Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and
> 'probesize' options Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:0':
> Metadata:
> major_brand     : isom
> minor_version   : 512
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
> encoder         : Lavf58.45.100   Duration: 00:00:46.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 960x400, 2882 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc
> (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
> Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 123 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))   Stream #0:1 ->
> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp2 (native)) [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55dfc34c2100] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file pipe:0: Invalid
> data found when processing input Cannot determine format of input
> stream 0:0 after EOF Error marking filters as finished Conversion
> failed!

My question is: What do I need to change in the command to successfully finish the process with the second file?

**Update:**

I tried with `-analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647` and with `-probesize 4G -analyzeduration 10G` but it still produces the same error.

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -s 800x600 -f mpeg pipe:1
```

**2nd Update:**
When I use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before input I'm getting `Option pixel_format not found`. Using after `-i` as output param doesn't change a thing.

This is the full ffprobe info about mp4 I'm dealing with

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "coded_width": 1280,
            "coded_height": 720,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "film_grain": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 31,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "field_order": "progressive",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "id": "0x1",
            "r_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "time_base": "1/24000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 4393389,
            "duration": "183.057875",
            "bit_rate": "3001682",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "4389",
            "extradata_size": 45,
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandler",
                "vendor_id": "[0][0][0][0]"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
            "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "id": "0x2",
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 8790000,
            "duration": "183.125000",
            "bit_rate": "128606",
            "nb_frames": "8585",
            "extradata_size": 5,
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "eng",
                "handler_name": "Stereo",
                "vendor_id": "[0][0][0][0]"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "sample_1280x720_surfing_with_audio.mp4",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "183.147000",
        "size": "71753110",
        "bit_rate": "3134230",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "isom",
            "minor_version": "512",
            "compatible_brands": "isomiso2avc1mp41",
            "encoder": "Lavf58.45.100"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests "`Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options`"? The problem could stem from the fact that you may not be able to seek pipe so if `ffprobe` needs to rewind, it'll fail and could produce 'partial file' error.

Comment: Yes, I tried with `-analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647` before input pipe, it still output the same error.

Comment: OK. Several other things you can try if you haven't already.

(1) You only showed the format info off ffprobe while the error is on the video stream. If you use `sample_1280x720_surfing_with_audio.mp4` instead of `pipe:0`, does your command work?  (2) If you dump that memory block to a file, say `output.mp4` and use it this time instead of `pipe:0`, does your command still work? (3) The other error message says it cannot figure out `pix_fmt`. What happens if you specify `pix_fmt` input option (whatever ffprobe says it is)

Comment: One other thing. The sample MP4 file may not have its MOOV atom at the beginning of the file, which forces pipe seeking. [See this answer](https://superuser.com/a/438471). What happens if you re-encode "sample_1280x720_surfing_with_audio.mp4" to make sure the MOOV is at the top.

Comment: I update the q with more details upon your suggestions. Not sure about your last comment with MOOV, I tried to move it around as part of the output param but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the location of the MP4's MOOV atom, which must be read first to demux the container. When the MOOV atom is placed at the end of the file, FFmpeg needs to read ahead to the end of the file to retrieve this atom then *seek* back to the beginning to process the file. There lies the issue: Pipes do not allow seeking. Hence, the OP's error.

I've verified the behavior on FFmpeg 5.0 in Python/Windows as follows.

First, read in a non-working MP4:

```py
mp4file = 'test.mp4'
with open(mp4file,'rb') as f:
    b = f.read()

print(len(b),b.find(b'moov'))
```

This printed

```
423691, 421513
```

indicating the `moov` atom is placed at the end of the file.

Then, I moved the `moov` atom to the beginning by

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -codec copy -movflags faststart fasttest.mp4
```

When you run this, the FFmpeg log will contain:

```
[mp4 @ 00000148fe2eba40] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
```

Now, I repeat the search for the `moov` atom:

```py
mp4file = 'fasttest.mp4'
with open(mp4file,'rb') as f:
    b1 = f.read()

print(len(b1),b1.find(b'moov'))
```

This printed

```
423711, 36
```

And inputting `b1` bytes into FFmpeg running as a subprocess with piped stdin worked:

```py
sp.run(['ffmpeg','-i','-','-f','mp4','-codec','copy','NUL','-y'], input=b1)
```

So, unfortunately, it appears the only way to make this work is to screen the input memory for the location of `moov` atom and error out citing incompatible mp4 file. If .net offers a memory-mapped file support, you can place the data as such file and FFmpeg may work with that. All else, you may need to resort to dumping the data to a temp file.

P.S., If you want to find out exactly how this behavior happens, you can review [the `mov.c` source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mov.c)

Comment: I guess this stands the same for the situation with the input stream. I  cannot use mp4 as the input stream, so I'll need to rely on temp files for input and output

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be the case. With fast SSD/NVMe drives, hopefully it won't hinder your performance too much